# Use switch case in Blazor for attribute

Tags: switch-statement, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I would like to set the css class in blazor using property enum. Programmatically, a switch case would make sense.

**How do I write a switch case for a attribute in Blazor?**

at cs file:

```cs
public enum PastPresentFuture
{
    PAST,
    PRESENT,
    FUTURE
}

public MyObject
{
    public PastPresentFuture PastPresentFuture { get; set; }
}
```

at css file:

```css
    
.past{
    color: grey;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.present {
    color: black;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.future {
    color: black;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

at razor - file I tried: (NOT WORKING!)

```cs
<div class="
     @switch(myObject.PastPresentFuture)
     {
        case PastPresentFuture.PAST: past break; 
        case PastPresentFuture.PRESENT: present break;
        case PastPresentFuture.FUTURE: future break;
     } 
     one-more-class">
```

also I tried using a span: (NOT WORKING!)

```
case PastPresentFuture.PAST: <span>past</span> break;
```

I get the **error**:

> RZ9979    Code blocks delimited by '@{...}' like '@{ switch(currentSitzungsAndUvsDays[i].PastPresentFuture){case PastPresentFuture.PAST:break; case PastPresentFuture.PRESENT:break;case PastPresentFuture.FUTURE:break;} }' for attributes are no longer supported These features have been changed to use attribute syntax. **Use 'attr="@(x => {... }"'**.

**I can't find the right syntax for the switch case inside a Blazor class attribute.**
You know how to do?

My current workaround: (works)

```cs
<div class="
  @(myObject[i].PastPresentFuture == PastPresentFuture.PAST ? "past" : 
    myObject[i].PastPresentFuture == PastPresentFuture.PRESENT ? "present" : "future") 
      day">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method that returns the css class:

```cs
<div class="@GetCssClass(currentSitzungsAndUvsDays[i])">
    ...
</div>
```

```cs
string GetCssClass(MyObject myObject)
{
   return myObject.PastPresentFuture switch
   {
       PastPresentFuture.PAST => "past",
       PastPresentFuture.PRESENT => "present",
       PastPresentFuture.FUTURE => "future"
   };
}
```